# BLToolkit: how to get master-detail result set using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, bltoolkit

Here is an example usage of list associations taken from [BLToolkit documentation](http://www.rsdn.ru/projects/rfd/linq/LinqWithBLToolkit.xml):

```
from p in db.Product
select new
{
  p.OrderDetails.Count,
  p.ProductName
};
```

where

```
class Product
{
  [PrimaryKey, Identity]
  public int ProductID;

  public string ProductName;

  [Association(ThisKey="ProductID",  OtherKey="ProductID")]
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails;
}
```

Is it possible to get list of products with order details for each product like this:

```
from p in db.Product
select new
{
  Details = p.OrderDetails,
  p.ProductName
};
```

The code above throws LinqException with the following message:

Cannot find converter for the 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[OrderDetail, TestProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the normal linq to sql provider this would work fine. With the BLToolkit Linq provider I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please suggest what SQL query would be generated for this expression by normal LINQ to SQL provider?

Comment: The query you have written should work fine in Linq2Sql.
For BLToolkit, check out: http://groups.google.com/group/bltoolkit/browse_thread/thread/85c00c8d80072e5c
"This feature is not supported yet"

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the answer I was looking for: not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used the BLToolkit, you might try to use a class you define rather than relying on an anonymous type.

That is, you could define a class called `MyOrder` that has properties `String ProductName` and `List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails`, and then change your linq query to something like:

```
from p in db.Product
select new MyOrder
{
  OrderDetails = p.OrderDetails,
  ProductName = p.ProductName
};
```

I can't guarantee that this would work, but it's probably worth a shot (unless someone posts something more definitive).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, your code raises the same error. LINQ expression parser doesn't care whether it's normal class or anonymous compiler-generated class used in **select** clause, both of them work well in the first example.